# Unable to play mp4 videos in AVPlayer

Tags: objective-c, video, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

[image]I'm using AVPlayer to play videos. I couldn't play .mp4 videos.I'm getting this black screen. here is my code.

```
`NSString *filePath = [self.videoArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType: @"mp4];
url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
video=[AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
playerViewController.player = _video;
playerViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;
[video play];
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];`
```

Comment: Using `NSLog` or debug point check filepath or soundFilePath have a proper value or not? Also provide more detail like error log you got.

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: So your URL is wrong. `self.video_Array ` in this array which URLs are there, its a HTTP link or its a local url.

Comment: Give me one of your URL. if possible, because according your code it seems you are trying to play video which are in your `bundle`.

Comment: file path is right, but sound filePath shows nil value. check my above code

Comment: You need to provide `filePath` so that I can be help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code I think it would be working for you, because It seems your URL is not for bundle its from web.

```
// your filepath which is may be "http" type
NSString *filePath = [self.video_Array objectAtIndex:index];
// http to NSURL using string filepath
NSURL *url= [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filePath];
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
playerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
video=[AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
playerViewController.player = _video;
playerViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;
[video play];
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added 2 video files with same name. That was the problem.